# Duplicate Namespace in header for error response from SOAP web service

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, weblogic

If I send a request with the header like as below .,

```
<S:Header>
  <ns2:transId xmlns="http://test.ws.com/testws"           
  xmlns:ns2="http://test.db.com/db9">123ASD89EDFE7363</ns2:transId>
</S:Header>
```

its working fine for success responses also there is no unnecessary namespace exist in the header. But error cases, the response from the web service is sent with the two namespaces using same default identifiers for the header element as like below.,

```
<S:Header>
  <transId xmlns="http://test.ws.com/testws"   
  xmlns="http://test.db.com/db9">123ASD89EDFE7363</transId>
</S:Header>
```

because of the above format, the client application is unable to parse the responses.

the client artifact is generated using the clientgen from the wsdl. can anyone please help to find the resolution for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe the issue a little more?

It sounds like you're making an HTTP request with a header that has the value "123ASD...", and that when the server responds with OK (200) then it works as expected, but that when the server responds with an error condition (4xx-5xx) then the response it bad.

is it duplicating the same header twice in the HTTP response headers?

Or is it sending an extra request (like perhaps a redirect)?

Like

GET   gets a 301 repsonse with the header and then maybe it sends to an error page but it uses the same header twice or something?

A little more information about the header value (does it change every time?) might help...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. its a SOAP message with header and body over HTTP and there is no issues with the HTTP. error response is like the soap fault or schema validation error from the server when we send bad soap requests.    Its not duplicating the header, but when a soap request sent with the unnecessary namespace    xmlns="http://test.ws.com/testws" (it has nothing to do with the header elements but my client app adds this everytime when it sends request ), the web service returns the response including the above one and the needed namespace of xmlns="http://test.db.com/db9". my question is the web service is not using different identifiers when it sends two namespaces. the header value is static during one transaction like sessionid.